# Optimizing select query with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, db2

My query goes like this. If I just run the query without a distinct, it takes only 11 seconds. While it takes 46 seconds to run with distinct.  Any advice on how this can be optimized?

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT DISTINCT   ELIGIBLE_TO_SIGN_DT 
 , LAST_NAME 
 , FIRST_NAME 
 , EXTENDED_LAST_NAME 
 , DT_OF_BIRTH 
 , BIRTH_COUNTRY_ID 
 , REG_BY 
 , LAST_UPDATED_BY 
 , REVIEW_STATUS_1 
 , REVIEW_STATUS_2 
 , REVIEW_STATUS_3 
 , MLSB_MATCH_FILTER 
 , REG_STATUS_ID 
 , REG_STATUS 
 , HAS_TRAVELED 
 , PLAYER_ID_SHOW 
 , MLSB_MATCH 
 , TRAINER_AGENT_NAME 
 , NATIONAL_ID 
 , RES_FOLLOW_UP 
 , ATTACHMENT 
 , COMMENTS 
 , PLAYER_ID 
 , CHECKBOX 
 , INTL_AMA_ENTRY_ID 
 , ALSO_REG_BY 
 , MIDDLE_NAME 
 , BIRTH_COUNTRY_NAME 
  FROM AS_INTL_ADMIN_REG_VIEW 
  where VARCHAR_FORMAT(ELIGIBLE_TO_SIGN_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= date('07/02/2015') AND VARCHAR_FORMAT(ELIGIBLE_TO_SIGN_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= date('08/31/2015') 
 )  order by  case when UPPER(LAST_NAME) is null or trim(UPPER(LAST_NAME)) = '' then 'ZZZZZZ' else UPPER(LAST_NAME) end ASC,  case when FIRST_NAME is null or trim(FIRST_NAME) = '' then 'ZZZZZZ' else FIRST_NAME end ASC
 limit 200 offset 0
```

Comment: check Query execution plan to see the cost of distinct.

Comment: My execution plan did not have distinct at all in it. Moreover i see the same cost whether there is distinct keyword or not.

Comment: post the execution plan also along with this

Comment: I am unable to paste it here. I am naive. please bear with me. Give me your mail id

Comment: you want all distinct values or particular distinct value column ?

Comment: Why would you perform UPPER on a name before checking whether it is null or empty? Perhaps you could make such expressions as result fields of your subquery, so the outer query already has something to sort by. If you know that you'll have at least 200 players with a name, then maybe you can exclude those without.

Comment: If `ELIGIBLE_TO_SIGN_DT` is an actual date/timestamp type, don't convert it, the comparison to a date should work fine.  If it's a timestamp, [the end comparison should be an exclusive upper-bound(`<`)](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (the problem is really about how numbers are represented and is universal, SQL Server just has a couple extra wrinkles).  I get worried when I see `DISTINCT` applied to something this wide (usually it'll always be unique, or a subset will always be unique anyways...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the example as written is your actual code, then the difference is accounted for by the LIMIT you have on the query. When you run it without the DISTINCT, the query engine can just take the first 200 rows. But with the DISTINCT, it must first run on the entire table to find the distinct rows, then select the first 200.

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT is costly, ORDER BY ... UPPER()... can be costly

In the query given, it seems likely to me that DISTINCT is being used unnecessarily or to fix duplicates that shouldn't be there.  If the data is bad, consider fixing it rather than working around it.

Make sure you have a case insensitive index built
create index myindex on mytable UPPER(LAST_NAME)